# moveit takes a lot of time for plan and execute

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi community,
I'm a newbie of ROS and i had started to work with a Yumi robot of ABB (IRB 14000).
In order to use ROS Kinetic (with ubuntu 16.04) with this robot i followed these [guides and installed these packages](https://github.com/kth-ros-pkg/yumi/wiki/Installation)
Now i'm in some trouble with the trajectory planning mainly because:

1. The trajectory planning takes a lot of time also for very easy poses: [for example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f6bul6Mjw3o)
2. The planners do "whatever they want"
   (but probably i fixed with my old
   question [link
   text](https://answers.ros.org/question/363917/how-to-use-planners-in-moveit/))
3. Sometime the planner does not compute the path for no reason

I searched a lot in the web and i had setted/changed different parameters in the ompl_planning.yaml file. For example now i'm using:

```
  RRTstarkConfigDefault:
type: geometric::RRTstar
termination_condition: Iteration[10]
range: 0.0  # Max motion added to tree. ==> maxDistance_ default: 0.0, if 0.0, set on setup()
goal_bias: 0.05  # When close to goal select goal, with this probability? default: 0.05
delay_collision_checking: 1  # Stop collision checking as soon as C-free parent found. default 1
```

Is there are also a "good way" to program the motion? I followed all the tutorials regarding Python language because is the one that i'm using and the code written by me is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


import copy
from typing import Any
from moveit_msgs.msg import *
from moveit_commander import *
from std_msgs.msg import String
import geometry_msgs.msg
from yumi_utils import PI, gripper_effort
from yumi_hw.srv import *
from tf.transformations import quaternion_from_euler, concatenate_matrices, euler_matrix, quaternion_from_matrix


# Arm IDs
RIGHT = 1  # :ID of the right arm
LEFT = 2  # :ID of the left arm
BOTH = 3  # :ID of both_arms

# Defining the measure of the table
table_height = 0.025  # [m] :The height of the upper surface of the table (z)
table_length = 1.200  # [m] :The width of the table (y)
table_width = 0.400  # [m] :The width of the table (x)

# Length of the Gripper from datasheet
z_gripper = 0.136  # [m]

# Distance of the center of the cam from yumi_link_7_r
z_cam = 0.040  # [m]

# Length of the test tube
length_tube = 0.125  # [m]

# Choice of the planners
planner = "RRTstarkConfigDefault"  # Asymptotic optimal tree-based planner
# planner = "ESTkConfigDefault"  # Default: tree-based planner
# planner = "RRTConnectConfigDefault"  # Tree-based planner
# planner = "PRMstarkConfigDefault"  # Probabilistic Roadmap planner

planning_attempts = 100  # planning attempts
planning_time = 50  # [s] Planning time for computation

# Defining the workspace [min X, min Y, min Z, max X, max Y, max Z]
ws_R = [0.000, -table_length/2, table_height, 0.600, 0.200, 0.593]
ws_L = [0.000, -0.200, table_height, 0.600, table_length, 0.593]

# Initialization of the Node
rospy.init_node('demo_test', anonymous=True, log_level=rospy.DEBUG)
# Initialization of Moveit
rospy.loginfo('Starting the Initialization')
roscpp_initialize(sys.argv)

robot = RobotCommander()
scene = PlanningSceneInterface()
mpr = MotionPlanRequest()
rospy.sleep(1.0)

# Left arm
group_l = MoveGroupCommander("left_arm")
# Type of planner
group_l.set_planner_id(planner)
group_l.set_pose_reference_frame("yumi_body")

# Setting the workspace
group_l.set_workspace(ws=ws_L)

# Replanning
group_l.allow_replanning(True)
group_l.set_goal_tolerance(0.005)
group_l.set_num_planning_attempts(planning_attempts)
group_l.set_planning_time(planning_time)

# Right arm
group_r = MoveGroupCommander("right_arm")
# Type of planner
# group_r.set_planner_id(planner)
group_r.set_pose_reference_frame("yumi_body")

# Setting the workspace
group_r.set_workspace(ws=ws_R)

# Replanning
group_r.allow_replanning(True)
group_r.set_goal_tolerance(0.005)
group_r.set_num_planning_attempts(planning_attempts)
group_r.set_planning_time(planning_time)

# Both arms
group_both = MoveGroupCommander("both_arms")
# Type of planner
# group_both.set_planner_id(planner)

# Pose reference frame is the yumi_body
group_both.set_pose_reference_frame("yumi_body")
# Replanning
group_both.allow_replanning(True)
group_both.set_goal_tolerance(0.005)
group_both.set_num_planning_attempts(planning_attempts)
group_both.set_planning_time(planning_time)

# Publish the trajectory on Rviz
rospy.Publisher('/move_group/display_planned_path', moveit_msgs.msg.DisplayTrajectory, queue_size=20)
rospy.sleep(1.0)


# clean the scene

rospy.loginfo('Cleaning of the objects in the scene')
try:
    scene.remove_world_object("table")
    scene.remove_world_object("input_rack")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

rospy.sleep(0.5)

# add the table table
rospy.loginfo('Adding the table object')
table_pose = PoseStamped()
table_pose.header.frame_id = "yumi_body"
table_pose.pose.position.x = 0.150 + table_width / 2
table_pose.pose.position.y = 0.0
table_pose.pose.position.z = table_height / 2
scene.add_box("table", table_pose, size=(table_width, 1.2, table_height))

x_input_rack = 0.175
y_input_rack = 0.260
z_input_rack = 0.075
input_rack_pose = PoseStamped()
input_rack_pose.header.frame_id = "yumi_body"
input_rack_pose.pose.position.x = 0.3465
input_rack_pose.pose.position.y = 0.38090
input_rack_pose.pose.position.z = table_height + 0.075/2
scene.add_box("input_rack", input_rack_pose, size=(x_input_rack, y_input_rack, z_input_rack))


# Points useful: need to compute the pose
# Rendezvous_picking_point: center of the rack at an height of 10 cm more
rendezvous_picking_pose = Pose()
rendezvous_picking_pose.position.x = 0.3465
rendezvous_picking_pose.position.y = 0.38090
rendezvous_picking_pose.position.z = table_height + 0.075/2
rendezvous_picking_pose.position.z += 0.100 + z_input_rack + z_gripper  # [m]

# Rotation of 45 degrees of the end effector: method of the matrix rotations
R1 = euler_matrix(0, PI, 0)
R2 = euler_matrix(0, 0, -PI / 4)
quaternion_rendezvous_picking = quaternion_from_matrix(concatenate_matrices(R1, R2))
rendezvous_picking_pose.orientation.x = quaternion_rendezvous_picking[0]
rendezvous_picking_pose.orientation.y = quaternion_rendezvous_picking[1]
rendezvous_picking_pose.orientation.z = quaternion_rendezvous_picking[2]
rendezvous_picking_pose.orientation.w = quaternion_rendezvous_picking[3]

# Picking input rack point A1
# TODO: Think how to repeat programmatically the placing process
# Same column deltas of the output rack
dx_tube = 0.02150  # [m]
dy_tube = 0.0130  # [m]
pick = Pose()
# TODO: TEST!!!! A1 POSE
# TODO: Convert these positions for the output rack instead of the input
pick.position = copy.deepcopy(rendezvous_picking_pose.position)
pick.position.x -= 0.09520
# pick.position.x -= 0.115
# pick.position.y -= 0.073
pick.position.y -= 0.05270
pick.orientation = copy.deepcopy(rendezvous_picking_pose.orientation)

# Home points
home_L = [0.300, 0.250, 0.380, 0, PI, 0]
home_R = [0.300, -0.250, 0.380, 0, PI, PI]
q_home_L = quaternion_from_euler(home_L[3], home_L[4], home_L[5])
q_home_R = quaternion_from_euler(home_R[3], home_R[4], home_R[5])

# Distance between the label of the test tube and the camera on z axis
dz_scan = length_tube/2 + z_cam

# Defining the Scan Pose starting from home
scan_L = Pose()
scan_L.position.x = home_L[0]
scan_L.position.y = home_L[1] - 0.125
scan_L.position.z = home_L[2] + dz_scan
scan_L.orientation.x = q_home_L[0]
scan_L.orientation.y = q_home_L[1]
scan_L.orientation.z = q_home_L[2]
scan_L.orientation.w = q_home_L[3]

scan_R = Pose()
scan_R.position.x = home_R[0]
scan_R.position.y = home_R[1] - 0.125
scan_R.position.z = home_R[2]
scan_R.orientation.x = q_home_R[0]
scan_R.orientation.y = q_home_R[1]
scan_R.orientation.z = q_home_R[2]
scan_R.orientation.w = q_home_R[3]

rospy.loginfo('Finished init')


def return_home():
    """
    Return to the home position
    :return:
    """
    group_l.set_start_state_to_current_state()
    group_l.set_pose_target(home_L)
    group_l.go(wait=True)
    group_l.stop()
    group_l.clear_pose_target(group_l.get_end_effector_link())
    group_r.set_start_state_to_current_state()
    group_r.set_pose_target(home_R)
    group_r.go(wait=True)
    group_r.stop()
    group_r.clear_pose_target(group_r.get_end_effector_link())


def cartesian(dest_pose, group, constraint=None):
    # type: (geometry_msgs.msg.Pose , MoveGroupCommander, Any) -> None
    """
    Create a cartesian path with a middle point
    :param dest_pose: Pose
    :param group: MoveGroupCommander
    :param constraint: Path Constraint
    :return: Nothing
    """
    waypoints = []
    # Initialize the waypoints: Pose object
    wpose = copy.deepcopy(group.get_current_pose().pose)
    # Initialize start pose: Pose object
    start_pose = copy.deepcopy(group.get_current_pose().pose)
    # Divide the steps in 4 parts
    for i in xrange(4):
        wpose.position.x += (dest_pose.position.x - start_pose.position.x) * 0.25
        wpose.position.y += (dest_pose.position.y - start_pose.position.y) * 0.25
        wpose.position.z += (dest_pose.position.z - start_pose.position.z) * 0.25
        waypoints.append(copy.deepcopy(wpose))
        rospy.logdebug('punto {} e\': \n {}'.format(i, waypoints[i]))
    fraction = 0.0
    attempts = 0
    plan = None
    while fraction < 1.0 and attempts < 5 * planning_attempts:
        attempts += 1
        (plan, fraction) = group.compute_cartesian_path(waypoints,
                                                        0.01,  # eef step: 1cm
                                                        jump_threshold=0.0,
                                                        avoid_collisions=True,
                                                        path_constraints=constraint)
        rospy.logdebug('attempts: {} fraction: {}%'.format(attempts, fraction*100))
    # ricalcolare il time della traiettoria!
    if fraction == 1.0:
        plan = group.retime_trajectory(robot.get_current_state(), plan, 1.0)
        rospy.loginfo('executing the plan')
        group.execute(plan, wait=True)
        group.stop()
    else:
        rospy.logerr('it doesn\'t complete the trajectory, fraction: {}%'.format(fraction*100))
        raise Exception('Exceeded the maximum time')


def picking_L():
    rospy.loginfo('going to rendezvous picking pose: {}'.format(rendezvous_picking_pose))
    group_l.set_start_state_to_current_state()

    # Open the gripper
    gripper_effort(LEFT, -10)
    gripper_effort(LEFT, 0)

    # Set the constraints for the picking:
    # Setting the Orientation constraint
    rospy.loginfo('Setting the orientation constraint')
    oc_L = OrientationConstraint()
    oc_L.link_name = "gripper_l_base"
    oc_L.header.frame_id = "yumi_body"
    oc_L.orientation = copy.deepcopy(rendezvous_picking_pose.orientation)
    oc_L.absolute_x_axis_tolerance = 0.1
    oc_L.absolute_y_axis_tolerance = 0.1
    oc_L.absolute_z_axis_tolerance = 0.1
    oc_L.weight = 1.0
    # Constraints should be a list
    oc_L_list = [oc_L]
    # Declaring the object constraints
    constraint_list_L = Constraints()
    constraint_list_L.orientation_constraints = oc_L_list

    # rospy.loginfo('Reorient of the arm')
    group_l.set_pose_target(rendezvous_picking_pose)
    reorient = group_l.plan()
    group_l.execute(reorient, wait=True)
    # group_l.set_path_constraints(constraint_list)
    rospy.logdebug('Setted the orientation constraint')
    # Go to pick position
    rospy.logdebug('Go to pick position: {}'.format(pick))
    cartesian(pick, group_l, constraint_list_L)

    pick_up = group_l.get_current_pose().pose
    pick.position.z = input_rack_pose.pose.position.z + z_input_rack/2 + 0.005 + z_gripper
    group_l.set_max_velocity_scaling_factor(0.10)

    cartesian(pick, group_l, constraint_list_L)

    # picking
    gripper_effort(LEFT, 10)

    # go up
    rospy.loginfo('going up')
    cartesian(pick_up, group_l, constraint_list_L)
    group_l.clear_path_constraints()

    # returning to rendezvous
    rospy.loginfo('going to rendezvous')
    group_l.set_max_velocity_scaling_factor(1.0)
    group_l.set_max_acceleration_scaling_factor(0.50)
    cartesian(rendezvous_picking_pose, group_l)


def rendez_to_scan_L():
    # TODO: Add the constraint of the workspace
    group_l.set_start_state_to_current_state()
    rospy.loginfo('starting from the rendezvous picking position')
    # reorient for barcode Scanning
    rospy.logdebug('reorient for barcode scanning')
    reorient = group_l.get_current_joint_values()
    reorient[-1] += PI/4
    group_l.set_joint_value_target(reorient)
    reorient_plan = group_l.plan(reorient)
    group_l.execute(reorient_plan, wait=True)
    # group_l.go(reorient, wait=True)
    group_l.stop()

    # Keep the orientation constraint
    oc_home_L = OrientationConstraint()
    oc_home_L.link_name = "gripper_l_base"
    oc_home_L.header.frame_id = "yumi_body"
    oc_home_L.orientation = copy.deepcopy(group_l.get_current_pose(oc_home_L.link_name).pose.orientation)
    oc_home_L.absolute_x_axis_tolerance = 0.1
    oc_home_L.absolute_y_axis_tolerance = 0.1
    oc_home_L.absolute_z_axis_tolerance = 0.1
    oc_home_L.weight = 1.0
    # Constraints should be a list
    oc_L_list = [oc_home_L]
    # Declaring the object constraints
    constraint_list_L = Constraints()
    constraint_list_L.orientation_constraints = oc_L_list

    # Go to home
    group_l.set_path_constraints(constraint_list_L)
    group_l.set_start_state_to_current_state()
    group_l.set_pose_target(home_L)
    plan_rendezvous_home = group_l.plan()
    group_l.execute(plan_rendezvous_home)
    group_l.stop()

    # Go to Scan
    cartesian(scan_L, group_l, constraint_list_L)


def run():
    global robot
    global group_l
    global group_r
    global group_both
    global scene
    global mpr

    return_home()
    picking_L()
    rendez_to_scan_L()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
    rospy.loginfo('finished')
    roscpp_shutdown()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/365579/moveit-takes-a-lot-of-time-for-plan-and-execute/) by [Kappa95](https://answers.ros.org/users/61250/kappa95/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2020-11-14

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jschornak](https://answers.ros.org/users/37574/jschornak/) on 2020-11-14**:
I would suggest adding some info to this question:

- Copy and paste the logs from motion planning and trajectory execution.
- Can you provide an example of the third problem you mention, where the planner fails to compute a trajectory "for no reason"? When I've run into this problem before there's always a reason, but it's usually subtle and hard to find :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In this section of your code:

```
 # Choice of the planners
planner = "RRTstarkConfigDefault"  # Asymptotic optimal tree-based planner
# planner = "ESTkConfigDefault"  # Default: tree-based planner
# planner = "RRTConnectConfigDefault"  # Tree-based planner
# planner = "PRMstarkConfigDefault"  # Probabilistic Roadmap planner

planning_attempts = 100  # planning attempts
planning_time = 50  # [s] Planning time for computation
```

you tell MoveIt to use the `RRTstarkConfigDefault` planner config and set `planning_time` to 50 seconds. This planner is an "asymptotic optimal" planner, which means that after finding an initial feasible solution it will continue to plan to try to find better solutions until it reaches its time limit. In your video I can see that this planner finds its initial solution very quickly after you trigger the planning request, but only returns its solution after 50 seconds have elapsed, which matches the value you've set for `planning_time`.

Have you tried switching to a different planner like `ESTkConfigDefault` or `RRTConnectConfigDefault`? RRTConnect, for example, will return as soon as it finds an initial solution, which is useful if you want quick answers to plans of varying complexity. Or, you could try reducing `planning_time`, though there's a risk that if you pick a very short time limit the planner might not be able to find even an initial solution before timing out if the problem is very complicated.

The Open Motion Planning Library that MoveIt uses provides documentation about each of these planning algorithms [here](http://ompl.kavrakilab.org/planners.html), which could be useful for selecting which one is best for your application.

---

Originally posted by [jschornak](https://answers.ros.org/users/37574/jschornak/) with karma: 340 on 2020-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kappa95](https://answers.ros.org/users/61250/kappa95/) on 2020-11-15**:
Thank you so much for your answer: actually i misunderstood the method: `set_planning_time(planning_time)` as the maximum time in which the planner should find a solution... Infact this solved the time. But sometimes is not able to compute any motion.
Actually i'm trying all the planners that i have commented in my code and i have notice that they provide different solutions and sometimes the pose of the robot is too approximate or far from the target (4-10mm from the target on some direction). Also i have the issue of "incomplete motion", i mean that the planner doesn't plan or find a solution for the motion and i don't understand why.

I'm going to step with this project in order to learn ROS with calm starting with "easier" targets and later switch to a vision system for fetching the target positions for picking and placing also.